# pre-commit run The path python3.6 (from --python=python3.6) does not exist

Tags: jupyterhub, pre-commit.com

I am trying to follow the [contributing docs for JupyterHub](https://github.com/jupyterhub/jupyterhub/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md) and am getting an error when I run `pre-commit run`

The error is related to my python version. It's expecting `3.6` for some reason even though everything was installed with Python `3.7.3`. Here is the output running the command:

```
(.hub)  {~/jupyter/jupyterhub} (master %)$  pre-commit run
[INFO] Initializing environment for https://github.com/asottile/reorder_python_imports.
[INFO] Initializing environment for https://github.com/ambv/black.
[INFO] Initializing environment for https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit-hooks.
[INFO] Installing environment for https://github.com/asottile/reorder_python_imports.
[INFO] Once installed this environment will be reused.
[INFO] This may take a few minutes...
An unexpected error has occurred: CalledProcessError: Command: ('/Users/nicholasbrady/jupyter/jupyterhub/.hub/bin/python3', '-mvirtualenv', '/Users/nicholasbrady/.cache/pre-commit/repo5hv9ofak/py_env-python3.6', '-p', 'python3.6')
Return code: 3
Expected return code: 0
Output: 
    The path python3.6 (from --python=python3.6) does not exist

Errors: (none)

Check the log at /Users/nicholasbrady/.cache/pre-commit/pre-commit.log
```

If I check the logs, this is what it says:

```
(.hub)  {~/jupyter/jupyterhub} (master %)$  cat /Users/nicholasbrady/.cache/pre-commit/pre-commit.log
An unexpected error has occurred: CalledProcessError: Command: ('/Users/nicholasbrady/jupyter/jupyterhub/.hub/bin/python3', '-mvirtualenv', '/Users/nicholasbrady/.cache/pre-commit/repo5hv9ofak/py_env-python3.6', '-p', 'python3.6')
Return code: 3
Expected return code: 0
Output: 
    The path python3.6 (from --python=python3.6) does not exist

Errors: (none)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/nicholasbrady/jupyter/jupyterhub/.hub/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pre_commit/error_handler.py", line 46, in error_handler
    yield
  File "/Users/nicholasbrady/jupyter/jupyterhub/.hub/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pre_commit/main.py", line 316, in main
    return run(args.config, store, args)
  File "/Users/nicholasbrady/jupyter/jupyterhub/.hub/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pre_commit/commands/run.py", line 295, in run
    install_hook_envs(hooks, store)
  File "/Users/nicholasbrady/jupyter/jupyterhub/.hub/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pre_commit/repository.py", line 215, in install_hook_envs
    hook.install()
  File "/Users/nicholasbrady/jupyter/jupyterhub/.hub/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pre_commit/repository.py", line 93, in install
    self.prefix, self.language_version, self.additional_dependencies,
  File "/Users/nicholasbrady/jupyter/jupyterhub/.hub/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pre_commit/languages/python.py", line 168, in install_environment
    _make_venv(env_dir, python)
  File "/Users/nicholasbrady/jupyter/jupyterhub/.hub/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pre_commit/languages/python.py", line 180, in make_venv
    cmd_output(*cmd, env=env, cwd='/')
  File "/Users/nicholasbrady/jupyter/jupyterhub/.hub/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pre_commit/util.py", line 153, in cmd_output
    returncode, cmd, retcode, output=(stdout, stderr),
pre_commit.util.CalledProcessError: Command: ('/Users/nicholasbrady/jupyter/jupyterhub/.hub/bin/python3', '-mvirtualenv', '/Users/nicholasbrady/.cache/pre-commit/repo5hv9ofak/py_env-python3.6', '-p', 'python3.6')
Return code: 3
Expected return code: 0
Output: 
    The path python3.6 (from --python=python3.6) does not exist

Errors: (none)
```

I tried to clear the cache since it looked like it was referring to a cache that might have existed when I had python 3.6

```
(.hub)  {~/jupyter/jupyterhub} (master %)$  pre-commit clean
Cleaned /Users/nicholasbrady/.cache/pre-commit.
```

but it didn't change the error at all, or the log.

Anyone know what this is? If not, hopefully I'll figure out soon and will add an answer when I do... :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The configuration for that repository sets [`language_version: python3.6`](https://github.com/jupyterhub/jupyterhub/blob/917786f2f5abdd5163770949c04f507ea0c23d84/.pre-commit-config.yaml#L6) which is why it is attempting to use python3.6

I'd suggest either changing that to `language_version: python3` or installing `python3.6`

Comment: oh!! I didn't even notice that ‍♂️I ended up editing the source code on pre-commit to use 3.7 with a static string 'python3.7'... Much better what you did!